# mat-table: span a row over all columns

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
 ----------------------------------------------
| First Name | Last Name |  Email  |   Phone   |
|----------------------------------------------|
|              No data Available               |
 ----------------------------------------------
```

I have to show a row "No data Available" when there is no data available in mat-table datasource. How can I achieve this in angular material?

Answer (score 0):

try

`<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.property??"No data Available"}} </td>`

the double question mark means if the item exists it will use that otherwise it will add the text after the question mark

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: I have edited the question, can you please take another look?